# Performance on sorting by populated field using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have learned that it is not possible to sort by populated field in mongodb during querying. Suppose I have a schema like below, and I have 1 million data in record. And i only need to return 10 records for each query, depending of the column sorting (asc/desc) and page defined. What are the effective solution to this problem?

Simplify problem:
In the front end, I will have a data table with column firstname, lastname, test.columnA and test.columnB. Each of this column is sortable by user.

My initial solution was to query everything out in mongoose, flattening it to json and using javascript to reorder and finally response the final 10 data only. But this will have bad performance impact with increasing data set.

```
var testSchema = {
    columnA: { type: String },
    columnB: { type: String },
}

var UserSchema = {
    firstname: { type: string },
    lastname: { type: string },
    test: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Test'
      }
}
```

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you using? Also, could you explain what do you mean with "it is not possible to sort by populated field in mongodb during querying"?

Comment: mongodb 3.2. It means it is not possible to sort the populated result as a whole via mongoose querying. AFAIK, there is no equivalent querying in mongodb which has similar result as this:`SELECT TOP(10) * FROM User LEFT JOIN Test WHERE User.id = Test.UserID ORDER BY columnA` where columnA is the populated field in this case.

Comment: and thus it left only the option of using `User.find().populate('test', 'columnA columnB')` to retrieve the entire result set and use the result for data manipulation to retrieve final stage of data similar to query on above comment. And this has bad impact on performance  if the User list is large(eg: 1 million record). Hope that I do explain it clearly.